# Delete user from back-end remove all things related it in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is this possible when remove user from back end then remove all the
things related it (delete data from custom table of that user)

I used `add_action( 'delete_user', 'my_delete_user' );` hook and also
execute delete query for delete data from custom table related that
user but data only deleted from **user** and **user_meta** table not delete
from custom table.

So anyone have idea for this (when I remove user from back end then
data should be deleted from custom table also)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hello guys!
>
> i resolved this issue by using same hook

```
add_action( 'delete_user', 'my_delete_user' );
```

> here is my code

```
<?php

function my_delete_user( $user_id ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $user_obj = get_userdata( $user_id );

    $id_user = $user_obj->ID;
    $idsss = $user_obj->user_id;


    /*Delete Data from friend table*/  
    $query_friend= $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM `wp_user_friends` where `friend_id` = ".$user_obj->ID."");

    /*delete data from group*/
    $delete_group_table =$wpdb->query("DELETE FROM `wp_group` where `user_id` = ".$user_obj->ID."");


}
add_action( 'delete_user', 'my_delete_user' );
?>
```

> Now it's working perfect.